# Sharing partition folder not working after reboot

Tags: networking, samba, reboot, file-sharing, sharing

I’m using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with 3 hard drive partitions.

I installed Samba and shared a folder in the network from the second partition, worked fine but after reboot, I cannot access that folder from the network. I have to mount and share every time I reboot.

I first installed Samba and gave all the necessary permissions by following the installation steps.

Comment: Is your partition mounted at boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the disk utility to mount the partition at boot:

[image]